# Android Fixed size dialog dimension- What is Major & Minor?

Tags: android, android-styles

What are these attributes stands for? The difference between **major** dimension and **minor** dimension?

```
<style name="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMajor">@dimen/dialog_fixed_width_major</item>
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMinor">@dimen/dialog_fixed_width_minor</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">@dimen/dialog_fixed_height_major</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">@dimen/dialog_fixed_height_minor</item>
.......
</style>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**windowFixedHeightMajor** :    A fixed height for the window along the major axis of the screen, that is, when in portrait.

**windowFixedHeightMinor**  : A fixed height for the window along the minor axis of the screen, that is, when in landscape.

**windowFixedWidthMajor** : A fixed width for the window along the major axis of the screen, that is, when in landscape.

**windowFixedWidthMinor** : A fixed width for the window along the minor axis of the screen, that is, when in portrait.

Comment: using this attributes gives error of "error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowFixedHeightMajor' is private"

Comment: Why does it have the name "fixed", if it's not fixed at all? It's a percentage for some of them...

Answer (score 3):

Using windowFixedHeightMajor or windowFixedHeightMinor do not compile as their marked private.

Comment: You parent theme should be of Dialog type.