# AlertDialog AppCompat width and height

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My custome style for AlertDialog look like:

```
<style name="Testing.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

I need change width and height, because it is too large on my tablet. Any ideas?

Below code not working properly:

```
   <item name="windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_major</item>
   <item name="windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/abc_dialog_min_width_minor</item>
```

Comment: `<item name="android:layout_width">50dp</item>`?

Comment: It's not working. Still to big

Comment: Get width using DisplayMerics for Window

Comment: How to make using only styles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is a customizes dialog box then you can set the height and width in new created XML file only. but if you are using AlertDialog.builder then use this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.
```

And follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907104/alertdialog-with-custom-view-resize-to-wrap-the-views-content) Hope it may help you out.

Answer (score 18):

I was able to adjust the width like so:

```
<style name="NarrowDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMajor">70%</item>
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMinor">70%</item>
</style>
```

`Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.NarrowDialog)...`

There is also a minimum width you might wish to adjust:

```
<item name="windowMinWidthMajor">65%</item>
<item name="windowMinWidthMinor">65%</item>
```

---

**Attribute details:**

- `windowFixedHeightMajor`:

A fixed height for the window along the major axis of the screen,
   that is, when in portrait.

- `windowFixedHeightMinor`:

A fixed height for the window along the minor axis of the screen, that is, when in landscape.

- `windowFixedWidthMajor`:

A fixed width for the window along the major axis of the screen, that is, when in landscape.

- `windowFixedWidthMinor`:

A fixed width for the window along the minor axis of the screen, that is, when in portrait.

Comment: How is this not accepted answer, thanks @Tim, for other: more info on attributes taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003591/android-fixed-size-dialog-dimension-what-is-major-minor#answer-29004580

Answer (score 6):

I found that an easier way is to set the style in styles.xml
and then set 
android:windowMinWidthMajor 
and android:windowMinWidthMinor

```
<style name="Testing.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item> 
</style>
```